# iOS App going in background - Need to remove removeFilePresenter using Graph

Tags: cosmicmind

I have a timer running in my app. When the app goes in background I realized I need to removeFilePresenter because otherwise the process is killed and when I am back in foreground my table cannot reload data.

How can I do that and reload my graph database as soon as the app comes back to foreground?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload your data in the viewDidLoad, or viewDidAppear lifecycle calls in any view controller. Even with many instances of Graph, it will always reference a single instance under the hood, so you don't have to worry about duplication or poorly managed resources.

Comment: Thank you so much. In fact the table was already reloading correctly (but not in the simulator, and I don't know why). Now I am trying to figure out how to force a sync with iCloud. If my database Is on my iPhone and then I install the app on an iPad, the database is indeed synced. But is it enough for me to ask for a db.sync anytime to force the sync to happen when the user install the app on a second device for the first time? Thanks again in advance. Great work!!

Comment: Thank you! For your immediate sync question, are you asking the best way to sync immediately and to decrease the latency on syncing?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your second answer. Yes, I was trying to sync decreasing latency. Best!